# Clear Regex for "URL Contains"

Tags: regex, url

I'm always stymied by regular expressions. My tool has a filtering option for "Current URL Matches Regex (case insensitive)" but I'm not sure how to write the regular expression for my needs. I'd love to figure out how to write a regex that would ONLY trigger for URLs that contain ANY of these 5 strings anywhere in URL:

Product=Neo-Supreme

Product=Cordura

Product=Hawaiian

Product=Animal%20Deluxe

Product=Camo

Comment: are you looking for URL validation as well? language please?

Comment: We need to know what tool you're using, at the very least. Running regex matches in `grep` is far different than SQL server or etc

Comment: The tool is an AB testing tool, visual website optimizer (VWO.com). They don't specify what language their regex is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the regex you need is something along the lines of

```
'Product\=[^&]+'
```

unless you know that the product can be something other than one of those 5 options.

If so, you'll need to use

```
'Product\=(Neo-Supreme|Cordura|Hawaiian|Animal%20Deluxe|Camo)'
```

EDIT for comments:
To match anything you can always use .*, which matches on any number of any character (except a newline, unless otherwise specified).

```
'.*seat-option.*Product\=(Neo-Supreme|Cordura|Hawaiian|Animal%20Deluxe|Camo).*'
```

[Here's a demo](http://regex101.com/r/lM9qR3/1)

Comment: the product can be another value, i want to limit just for those 5

Comment: @dubesor In that case try the second regex in my answer.

Comment: It worked with your suggestion. Current URL Matches Regex (case insensitive) = Product\=(Neo-Supreme|Cordura|Hawaiian|Animal%20Deluxe|Camo)

Comment: @dubesor In that case, could you mark the answer as correct for the benefit of anyone who may stumble upon this question in the future?

Comment: done, thank you! follow up question... how would i write a similar regex with a slightly broader condition for URL matches; i'm looking for a string that contains "seat-option" and the previous rule: [ANYTHING]seat-option[ANYTHING]Product\=(Neo-Supreme|Cordura|Hawaiian|Animal%20Deluxe|Camo)[ANYTHING]